# Codeigniter Rest API : Put request doesn't get passed id

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, rest, put

I developed a REST API using REST Library for Phil Sturgeon,
GET and POST requests working fine ,
Now when I try to access the passed params with PUT request, I get null.

```
class ApiItems extends REST_Controller
{
    function __construct()  {
    //
    }

    public function items_get(){  //   //}
    public function items_post(){  //   //}

    public function items_put()
    {       
        if(!$this->put('id'))         //My issue : I can't get the id here
        {
            $this->response(array('error' => 'Item id is required'), 400);
        }


        $data = array(
            'id'  => $this->put('id'),
            'code'=> $this->put('code'),
            'name'  => $this->put('name'),
            'quantity'  => $this->put('quantity')
        );

        $this->item_model->update_item($this->put('id'), $data);
        $message = array('success' => $id.' Updated!');
        $this->response($message, 200);
    }
}
```

I tested it using POSTMAN and I get this :
[POSTMAN PUT Call screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiHEx.jpg)

I dont understand why $this->get(id) or $this->post(id) are working fine,and not the case for $this->put(id)  ?

Comment: It's working ,I ve done a stupid mistake when filling the parameters with POSTMAN, I checked form-data instead of x-www-form-url-encoded

Answer (score 2):

It's working ,I ve done a stupid mistake when filling the parameters with POSTMAN, I checked form-data instead of x-www-form-url-encoded